# The limit of a sum with Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation

I am trying the fallowing exercise :
Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with $f(0)=0$

Compute the limite of :
$S_n=\sum _{k=0}^{n}f(\frac{k}{n^2})$

I used Taylor's theorem , so I have 
$$
f(\frac{k}{n^2})=f(0)+f'(0)(\frac{k}{n^2}-0)+h(\frac{k}{n^2})(\frac{k}{n^2}-0)
$$
with
$$
\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}h(\frac{k}{n^2})=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n^2})= \frac{f'(0)}{n^2} \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} k+\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^{n}h(\frac{k}{n^2})k
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n^2}) -\frac{f'(0)}{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}h(\frac{k}{n^2})k
$$
$$
\Longleftrightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n^2}) -\frac{f'(0)}{2}(1+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}h(\frac{k}{n^2})k
$$
Furthermore, Let $\epsilon>0$
$$
\exists  N\in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N \Longrightarrow |h(\frac{k}{n^2})|<\epsilon
$$

I cannot use this because I have $h(\frac{k}{n^2})$**k**..Someone has an idea to  get around the problem ?

Or another way to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the integral form of the remainder (see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) )
$$
f\left(\frac{k}{n^2} \right)=f(0)+\int_0^{\frac{k}{n^2}}f'(t)\,dt=\int_0^{\frac{k}{n^2}}f'(t)\,dt.
$$
Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary (fixed). Since $f'$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f'(0)-\varepsilon\leq f'(x)\leq f'(0)+\varepsilon$ for every $x\in(-\delta,\delta)$. Since $0\leq k\leq n$ thus $\frac{k}{n^2}\in(-\delta,\delta)$ for $n\geq n_0$. So, if $n\geq n_0$ then we have
$$
(f'(0)-\varepsilon)\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_0^{\frac{k}{n^2}}1\,dt\leq\sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n^2} \right)\leq (f'(0)+\varepsilon)\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_0^{\frac{k}{n^2}}1\,dt.
$$
From these inqualities it follows
$$
\lim_n S_n=\frac{f'(0)}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!So if $f \in C^0(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and only differential I guess I can't do the exercise ?

Comment: @Nico Sorry, something is missing in your comment. "differential" what? $f\in C^0(R,R)$ alone (with $f(0)=0$) is nout enough, take e.g. $f(x):=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: It's my fault, f differentiable, anyway I think I have succeeded. Thanks you for your time